# weird behavior using LinearLayout and layout:weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm reading a book about Android and I'm stuck here

Here are the instructions:

1. Use the Real UI project we recently created but let's start with a completely
   clean sheet for the layout. Right-click the layout folder in the project
   explorer. From the pop-up context sensitive options menu, choose New |
   Layout resource file.
2. Make sure LinearLayout is selected for the Root element.
3. Name the file list_detail_layout then left-click OK.
4. In the Properties window, find the orientation property of the
   LinearLayout, which is provided by default, and change it to horizontal.
5. Drag a LinearLayout(vertical) onto the design.
6. Now drag a LinearLayout(horizontal) onto the design
7. Select the first (vertical) LinearLayout within the root LinearLayout, find
   its layout:weight property, and set it to 40. Set its background to a color of
   your choice by finding and left-clicking the background property ellipses ...,
   then left-clicking the Color tab and choosing a color.
8. Select the second (horizontal) LinearLayout within the root LinearLayout,
   find its layout:weight property, and set it to 60. We now have two
   clearly discernible areas of the screen: one taking up 40%, the other 60%,
   as shown next:

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ZD0.png)
[image]
I follow all the steps but I still do not get the result of the image. This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I change both layout_width values to "wrap_content" it works but I don't know why is not mentioned in the book...

Comment: you need to assign weight sum. if weight sum = 1 then 40percent of it is .40

Comment: you have not given weight_sum on parent layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:layout_weight` attribute tells the LinearLayout how to distribute its children. If you give both widgets the same value, but that does not necessarily make them the same width on screen. To determine the width of its child views, LinearLayout uses a mixture of the `layout_width` and `layout_weight` parameters.

LinearLayout makes two passes to set the width of a view. In the first pass, LinearLayout looks at `layout_width`(or `layout_height`, for vertical orientation). If the value for `layout_width` for both of the LinearLayout is `wrap_content`, then each view will get only enough space to draw itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="60"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I guess you are a beginner. I want to mention you that writing your own code for UI design is a better practice than drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `weightSum` in the parent.

It should look like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. First layout looks bigger than second layout. It's not necessary assign a period before as well as android:weightSum="100" the behavior is the same 

pd: sorry my english

Comment: Try changing the layout_width in both the child linear layouts to wrap_content.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. But it's weird because is not mentioned in the book, whatever... It's resolved, thanks everybody.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if I could help you out. :)

Comment: @Abhriya Roy wrapping is not the concept behind weight sum

Comment: It has worked for me each and everytime, but I'll look into it further. Thank you for pointing it out. :)

Comment: working vs concept is two different things even if you use match parent it will work in the other way around meaning if you give 2 : 8 layout_weights layout which has 2 will be big in size and 8 will be small depends on the ratio .. in any ways weight sum was used to increase the  efficiency of the code as well .by doing wrap_ or match_ you are missing that

Comment: Yes. I was just checking it out. It does increase the efficiency. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **android:layout_weight** make sure either you have **android:weightSum** set in the parent LinearLayout or set the **android:layout_width = 0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60">
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```